# Is there a manual for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, documentation

Perhaps a wiki of sorts? I just want to find an official place that lists all functionality in current versions. So many features get cut and replaced over the years; surely there must exist a maintained canonical list of features per version somewhere?

I would like to find the manuals for both the Desktop and Mobile versions, by the way. Things I expect to be in them are keyboard shortcuts and gestures and the like. I'm not looking for developer documentation, as this is actually a lot easier to find and fairly up to date.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use google chrome's help page. https://support.google.com/chrome  It seems to be setup to provided information on functionality based on desired usage.

Comment: Yes! I guess that's it! It's pretty limited and unfortunately doesn't accept user input (wiki edits, comments, etc.), but it's definitely official.

Comment: I can understand your frustration when looking for something so simple.